# How to run a .bat or .vbs script from a particular folder using java programming

Tags: java, batch-file

I am new to java, 
I need to execute the run.vbs script from a particular folder say C:\Users\Application\Tools\run.vbs.
I am able to start the script from "windows run" by just giving the location i.e.
"C:\Users\Application\Tools\run.vbs" and clicking on "Enter". But, when i call the same scirpt using:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Application\\Tools\\run.vbs")
```

It is giving the error "unable to access the specified file xxxx.war" which is the file vbs script is accessing.

Comment: doesn't you need to escape backslashes with double backslashes?

Comment: A quick Google for the `exec()` function would have shown the [three-argument version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) does what you want

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start run.bat", null, "C:\\Users\\Application\\Tools"); is giving the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could/have to load the CMD command for executing BAT files.
The syntax is

```
cmd.exe /c <command name>.
```

The Java for this command will be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c <command name>");
```

For referencing: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

For running .VBS, this may be the way:

```
cscript <your_script>.vbs
```

or

```
wscript <your_script>.vbs
```

Java command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript <your_script>.vbs");
```

It is documented here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx

(My answer is Windows dependent.)