# How to run vbs file using SoapUI groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I used to run the vbs file in Java -Eclipse

myscript.vbs:

```
Function func
Dim Host
Set Host = CreateObject( "BZWhll.WhllObj" )
ResultCode = Host.Connect( "A" )
If ResultCode <> 0 Then
   Host.MsgBox "Error connecting to session A!", 4096
End If
Host.SendKey "A CICSMJ0"
Host.WaitReady 10, 1
Host.SendKey "<ENTER>"
End Function
func
```

java class written:

```
public class runvbs {

    public static void RunVBs(String jobName) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");         
            //Execute the vbscript name which is passed in this method.
            //Generally it is runmfjob.vbs is the vbscript to run as a pre-requisite.
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + currentDir + "\\vbscript\\" + jobName + ".vbs");
            boolean statusofjob;            
            //Every 60 seconds monitor the jobs and print the job is completed or not.
            //Do loop executes until the job is completed.
            do {                
                System.out.println("Mainframe Job is running and waiting to complete it");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } while (DataGenerator.getstatusofJob() == true);
            System.out.println("Vbscript is completed");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

The same needs to be converted groovy.. I have written as sample in soapui using groovy.

import java.io.IOException;

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript.exe C:\\Users\\3020722\\Desktop\\Navigator\\myScript.vbs");        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          log.info(ex)
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting `ActiveX component can't create object 'BZWhll.Whllobj'`

If i am giving `Dim Host As Object` and running showing it is `expecting end of statement` on that line..

When i run vbs file directly it is running.

Comment: Please check if the below thread helps! Note that it is no different from Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003568/how-to-run-a-bat-or-vbs-script-from-a-particular-folder-using-java-programming

Comment: I have tried that .. getting cant create ActiveX object from running soapui alone

Comment: Is your java program working? Also please take a look at this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319844/you-receive-a-activex-component-can-t-create-object-error-message-when

Comment: yes.. from Java it is working..

Comment: Working from where? Does it work when you copy the same program from Groovy script test step? or from eclipse? Also try to compare environment variable `PATH` .

Comment: i am running the same code from eclipse.. it is running

Comment: try comparing the `PATH` from both tools.